# How can I access private variables inside another class through inheritance?

Tags: c++, private-members

I am currently making a game and I am stuck figuring out how to access private variables through another class. I want the Enemies class private variables accessed to the Player class and through the 'setPlayerClass' function I want them added to the private variables of the current Player class. How do I make this work?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Enemies {
private:
    std::vector <std::string> enemies = { "Mutant Orc", "Mutant Bear", "Giant Elephant", "Giant Snake"};
    int enemyAttack = 5;
    int enemyHealth = 40;

public:

};

class PlayerClass {
private:
    int attackBonus;
    int healthBonus;

public:
    int returnWarriorBonus() {
        return attackBonus + 5 & healthBonus + 20;
    }

    void pickClass() {
        std::cout << "1. Warrior" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Player : private PlayerClass {
private:
    std::string playerName;

    int playerClass;
    int attack = 10;
    int health = 100;

    std::vector <int> healthPotions[2];

public:
    void setPlayerName(std::string x) {
        playerName = x;
    }

    std::string getPlayerName() {
        return playerName;
    }

    void setPlayerClass(int x) {
        while (true) {
            std::cout << "Choose class: " << std::endl;
            std::cin >> x;

            if (x == 1) {
                returnWarriorBonus();
            }
        }
    }
};

int main() {


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: By making the `private` variables `protected`.

Comment: I would go with the `protected` option as @user4581301 mentioned, but you can also declare it as a [friend class](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/friend-class-function-cpp) to access the private variables.

Comment: Both options are valid, and are certainly quick. But (for larger projects) they also impact maintainability (e.g. the freedom to change datatypes of private members without also having to change all the derived classes). An alternative is to add protected getter methods to you base class. If you then change the internal implementation of the baseclass you can modify the getters to still return the same information without having to change all your derived classes too

Comment: If you think you have a good reason for making certain members private, and a good reason for another class accessing those members, then your design is probably seriously flawed. *Why* does the `Player` class need to access private members of the `Enemies` class? Is it so a player can set each enemy's attack to `-12`? (Don't be blinded by your *intended* use of this access; consider all possible uses and weigh the risk against the benefit.) Is there another way to get the desired end result?

Comment: In other words do Enemy and Player need to communicate directly? Or is there some other class that will manage the game's logic and will use information from a player to update information in the Enemy class?

Comment: FWIW, there is a [template trick](http://bloglitb.blogspot.com/2011/12/access-to-private-members-safer.html) to access private members

Answer (score -1):

You can't access private variables but you can access protected

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).